# Bitshifting/exchanging 8 bits in a 16 bit word

Tags: bit-shift

I'm working on a project where I'd like to implement some bitshifting on a 16-bit word.

Specifically, I'm looking to shift the 8 least significant bits to become the 8 most significant bits and vice versa.

Note that I am NOT reversing or rotating the bits, as may have been asked in prior Stackflow questions.

For example, if I have the following 16 bit word:

0000 0000 0010 0110

I'd like to perform some sort of bit-wise or arithmetic operation to convert it to:

0010 0110 0000 0000

In essence, the least significant 8 bits exchange places with the most significant 8 bits.

BTW - Importantly, I'm working with 2's compliment binary values for these 16-bit words.

Any ideas on how to perform this operation?

All thoughts appreciated.  Thx.

Comment: This seems pretty basic.  Have you failed to mention some aspect of the problem that makes it non-trivial?  Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

1. Multiply the value by 256, giving temporary value A
2. Divide (integer division) value by 256, giving temporary value B
3. Use logical bitwise A or B, giving result C
4. Logical bitwise and 65535 with C, giving the final result.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply modulo and integer division:

```
x = x % 256 * 256 + x / 256;
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1, Use unsigned types.

Step 2: Let the compiler optimize the code.

```
unsigned swap2bytes(unsigned x) {
  //      LSB-->MSB     MSB-->LSB        Mask-off any higher order bits
  return ((x * 256) + ((x / 256) % 256)) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

This works with `unsigned` of any size.

Fixed width approach:

```
int16_t swap2bytes(int16_t x) {
  return x * 256u + x / 256u;
}
```